# Capture set time out from internal library?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with React.js in the browser. And currently we have a library that works with an slider that has an internal setTimeout.

I would like to do a

```
window.cleartimeout(ID from internal library set timeout)
```

Without having to come to a Pull Request to the library to expose that ID, is there any way to get the timeouts of the current page and clear the last timeout being applied?

Comment: No. You'll have to obtain a reference to the timeout handler setTimeout returned.

Comment: Thats, too bad, I thought this could be a problem that many people faced before, and having the control over timers or effects provided from a library should be something that the page should let me work with... the same way I do window.document.body and I access the body I should be able to say window.document.timers and get at least the timers in an stack

Comment: You can always initialize `window.timers = []` and then `window.timers.push(setTimeout(...))`. Though the reason it's not already done is that keeping a reference to a timer like that could potentially lead to a lot of no longer used memory never being garbage collected. Also how would one identify _which_ timer to stop? If you do it _explicitly_ then you have a chance of maybe coming up with a naming scheme.

Comment: Well, yes I see your point, but again garbage collecting things / schemas or ways to identify who provided a listener, is something that we could check too. I mean this does not happen with a simple button? you have also the button.events and you can see the event there... but I don't see something like that in the case of the timers. And I think is something that will come to memory leaks or errors when things come from libraries... We should be able to handle this situations, without memory leak or errors...

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv setTimeout returns an id not a reference to the timer. There will not be a GC problem.

Comment: @Oram Indeed it's an ID not a reference, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the `setTimeout` function.

```
window.timers = [];
window._setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(f, delay) {
    window.timers.push(window._setTimeout(f,delay));
};
```

This will give you a list of timer ids (it will not stop the timers from being GCed).

Now your problem will be to identify which id belongs to which timer... So I'd suggest you'll add some distinguishing info along with the timer id.

Comment: The provided solution is possible, though it will lead to override the current setTimeout implementation... this should come out of the box and supported by the browser itself from my point of view in a clear way....

Comment: Maybe you're right that it should come out of the box. But at least we can be happy that there is a solution.

Comment: I will probably do the PR to the library to be able to handle this in a cool way, but well this is also a possible solution that did not came to my mind, may be someone will come to say hey this is supported in this way... and I will be a happy man then.